# Freeze Header in gridview

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have the following GridView that is grouped

[image: picture]

The people are each the header of a group.

Is there a way to freeze header, so when the user scroll horizontally the screen, the headers are always visible ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just put the headers outside of the GridView. Alternatively don't use a `GridView` at all and put each row with a header and group items inside of a `ListView`. Then you can have a `Grid` in the `ItemTemplate`/`DataTemplate` that contains the header and a horizontal list of items. Another option is to simply not show group items since it might not work very well and simply allow to display them on another page after selecting one of the headers.